error: cannot find symbol when building android app in flutter using pdftron
I am trying to use the dependency https://pub.dev/packages/pdftron_flutter pdf tron to show pdf files in flutter app, when I try to build the android app, I get the error
     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\pdftron_flutter-1.0.1-      32\android\src\main\java\com\pdftron\pdftronflutter\helpers\PluginUtils.java:987: error: cannot       find symbol stringRes != R.string.document_save_error_toast_message; ^ symbol:   variable string location: class R
this is the flutter doctor output
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3447], locale      en-US) [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher) [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0) X cmdline-tools component is missing Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details. X Android license status unknown. Runflutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses. See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details. [√] Chrome - develop for the web [√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.34) [!] Android Studio (version 2022.3) X Unable to determine bundled Java version. [√] Android Studio (version 2023.3) [√] VS Code (version 1.92.1) [√] Connected device (4 available) [√] Network resources
I tried to implement all the solutions in the link "error: cannot find symbol" when building for Android in flutter
Like running flutter clean and changing compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion targetSdkVersion to 34,21,34 respectively but it did not work

I solved this answer by downgrading com.android.application version from 8.3.0 to 7.3.0

This issue was resolved by downgrading Gradle to 7.3.0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
